# How can run beanstalkq worker in detached mode in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, beanstalkd

we have implemented background jobs with Beanstalkq in rails application.

so, we have below gem in Gemfile.

```
gem 'stalker'
```

Now, with the help of below command we can start worker.

```
stalk jobs.rb
```

But, At EC2 server how can i run in detached mode. in documentation, there is no any appropriate solutions.

Can you please help with us.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks @Pentium10 !!! below answer was helpful for me.

Comment: Make sure you learn how to accept answers. Check the link for details.

Comment: Its implemented and working fine. also checked the link as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to try the screen command as

```
screen -d -m -S screen_name command
```

The `-S` option simply specifies inside which screen window the following command will be executed. As per `-d -m` the `man page` recites:

```
-d -m   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but
       doesn't  attach  to  it.  This  is  useful  for  system startup
       scripts.
```

Something like:

```
screen -d -m -S rails stalk jobs.rb
```

Then you can list your screen sessions with

```
screen -ls
```

And if you want to attach a screen session you use

```
screen -x [pid from the ls command above]
```

And if you hit `Control+A D` when in attached session, you detach it, or just close the shell/terminal window.

http://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/